# Is it possible to write recursive selectors in Sass?

Tags: recursion, sass

Is there a DRY way to write following rule in Sass? What I'm trying to achieve is to set margin-top ONLY for the first h2 in a section regardless of how deeply it's nested.

```
section  {
  $first : '> *:first-child';

    &,
    & #{$first},
    & #{$first} #{$first},
    & #{$first} #{$first} #{$first} {   
        > h2 {
            &:first-child {
                    margin-top: 33px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, only the first h2 in markup should be affected by the rule.

Comment: so, you want only the first h2 to be red. None of the others should be affected?

Comment: Right, but I don't know how deeply the first h2 is nested, so in one page it may be one level deep (div > h2) and in another four level deep (div > div > div > div > h2).

Comment: I don't think thats possible using pure css..

Comment: I'm asking about Sass, not pure css!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91380/discussion-between-shivi-and-smohadjer).

Comment: Wouldn't `div:first-child > h2` solve that issue globally in the first place?

Comment: No, it wouldn't, because div:first-child > h2 would also affect succeeding h2s that are inside a first-child div. For example in following example second h2 shouldn't be affected: 
<section>
 <div>
  <h2>first</h2>
  <div>
   <div>
    <h2>second</h2>
   </div> 
  </div>  
 </div>
</section>

Comment: Jup you are going to struggle. In this case, maybe what you are looking for it a `@for` loop that will repeat the amount of `>div` selectors every time. Still, this doesn't seem like something you should solve in CSS but in your HTML, by simple adding a class called 'first' to the `h2` _or_ making sure _you only have one h2_ - which in terms of styling, seems the most semantically correct (Your CSS will be unreadable otherwise, and a class is exactly made for this purpose, as is this element).

Comment: "...Your CSS will be unreadable otherwise". 
That's why I'm using Sass! Adding a "first" class" to the h2 is only possible via js after DOM is parsed since I don't know the exact structure of markup that is being generated by CMS, and I prefer not to rely on javascript for styling.

Comment: @smohadjer That is _not_ a good way of going about it. Is your fist styling _so_ important that it is worth the trade of of potentially hundreds of lines of identical code? Maybe use Javascript to style add the class, but otherwise it would look like the default - use Javascript to _enhance_ the CSS. Anyway, I posted an answer that will help you out. Just consider using a different technique as the output of SASS is still the thi9ng you will throw online.

Comment: Thanks, the Sass mixin does the job, but I'm not sure a mixin like this is better than a jquery solution of adding a "first-ever" class to h2. For one thing writing/debugging a jquery fn is easier (at least for me) than a Sass mixin. Anyway, at least now I know how to achieve what I wanted in Sass! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following mixin does what you want - to an extent. The problem with this is that you will create a whole bunch of style rules that need to be evaluated and discarded as you go on, and no matter how many you do, there can always be something nested deeper. This is a case where classes are more useful, and even good use of the tags available to you (like only allowing one h2 per page) would solve your problem better than this, but in essence, this works:

```
@mixin first-ever-child($select, $limit:20, $root:''){
    $nester: '>*:first-child';
    @for $i from 1 through $limit {
        $root: $root + $nester;
        #{$root + ' ' + $select}{ @content; }
    }
}

body {
    @include first-ever-child(' h2'){
        background: red;
    }
}
```

The above mixin will output the following by default (when pased a selector element, of course):

```css
body > *:first-child h2 {
  background: red;
}
body > *:first-child > *:first-child h2 {
  background: red;
}
body > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child h2 {
  background: red;
}
body > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child h2 {
  background: red;
}
body > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child h2 {
  background: red;
}
body > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child h2 {
  background: red;
}
body > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child h2 {
  background: red;
}
body > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child h2 {
  background: red;
}
body > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child h2 {
  background: red;
}
body > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child h2 {
  background: red;
}
body > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child h2 {
  background: red;
}
body > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child h2 {
  background: red;
}
body > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child h2 {
  background: red;
}
body > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child h2 {
  background: red;
}
body > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child h2 {
  background: red;
}
body > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child h2 {
  background: red;
}
body > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child h2 {
  background: red;
}
body > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child h2 {
  background: red;
}
body > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child h2 {
  background: red;
}
body > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child > *:first-child h2 {
  background: red;
}
```

This will protect you for up to 20 levels, but you can expand this of course by passing a limit. Be aware, though, the more style rules, the slower your site will get. I highly suggest taking another route for this.

#### Update

Heres a slightly more optimised version which even improves your output by making all your rules only declaration. Still pretty lengthy to evaluate, but better:

```
@mixin first-ever-child($select, $limit:20, $root:''){
    $nester: '>*:first-child';
    $nested: '';
    @for $i from 1 through $limit {
        $root: $root + $nester;
        @if str-length($nested) == 0 {
            $nested: $root;
        } @else {
            $nested: $nested + ', ' + $root;
        }
    }
    #{$nested}{ @content; }
}

body {
    @include first-ever-child(' h2'){
        background: red;
    }
}
```